# How to uninstall Windows 7 and get back Windows.old working

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uninstall

I have installed Windows 7 over Windows Vista. The Windows 7 setup has moved the previous (Windows Vista) installation in a folder Windows.old. Now I want to remove Windows 7 and get back Windows Vista. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Microsoft Help and Support article on how to do this. Read it carefully before attempting it. Best to also backup the hard drive in case something goes wrong.

[How to restore a Windows 7-based computer to a previous Windows installation by using the Windows.old folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Windows.old folder only keeps some of your files (e.g. the ones your system thinks are important). So, it is not possible to switch back to that. Also I don't understand why you want to do that, windows 7 and vista are pretty much the same, but 7 has less flaws.